# Python compare elements of tuples in a list separately

Tags: python, data-structures

[image]

I want to check if any of the tuples my list contain the specific variables “x” and “y”.

If tuple 1 contain “x”,”x” and tuple 2 contain “y”, “y” return should be false.

But if tuple 3 contain “x”,”y,” return should be true.

Also I don’t want the last element of any tuple to take part in the comparison.

**Edit:** I tried the solution suggested by schwobaseggl:

```
def check(lst, x, y):
    return any(x in tpl and y in tpl for tpl in (x[:-1] for x in lst))
```

Kinda works. However if node "a" and "b" is added, then edge "a" and "b", the edge "a" "a" also gets added why? (The tuple ('a',a',1) does not exist in this case. 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
def check(lst, x, y):
    return any(x in tpl and y in tpl for tpl in (x[:-1] for x in lst))
```

This uses a lazy generator over the tuples minus their respective last elements and `any` to check if it holds for, well, any of them that they contain both x and y.
For the more general case of more than 2 variables to be checked, you can use `all`:

```
def check(lst, *vars):
    return any(all(v in tpl[:-1] for v in vars) for tpl in lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a little faster using a numpy array.

```
t = [('a', 'b', '1'),('b', 'a', '2'), ('a', 'a', '2')]
print(np.array(t)[:,0] == np.array(t)[:,1])
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you just need one tuple to satisfy the condition, then we can return early if such condition is satisfied.

```
def check(list, x, y):
   for tuple in list[:-1]:
      if x in tuple and y in tuple:
         return true
```